# Stored procedure in SQL Server performs very slowly when used by many users

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a weird situation where I'm not quite sure what's happening with my stored procedure in my SQL Server 2016.

I have created two identical procedures which looks like following:

```
create procedure [dbo].[zsp_select_Transactions]
    (@SearchedUserId int,
     @StartDate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime)
as
     select 
         et.TransactionID, et.QuantityPurchased, 
         et.SalePrice, et.ItemID, et.Title
     from 
         Transactions et
     where 
         et.SearchedUserID = @SearchedUserId
         and et.TransactionDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
     order by 
         et.TransactionDate desc
```

And the second stored procedure looks exactly the same, but it just has a different name which is `zsp_select_Transactions2`

The `zsp_select_Transactions` procedure is currently used by large number of users and is being executed every second.

I have tried to run the procedure on my server's SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
 exec zsp_select_Transactions 75559,'2017-12-25','2018-01-25'
```

and:

```
exec zsp_select_Transactions2 75559,'2017-12-25','2018-01-25'
```

Please note the difference in the name for the procedures that are executed...

The results of these two have utterly shocked me, and I realize that there's something that I'm missing out here...

The first procedure (which is being used by all users, probably like 1000 users every single second) took 30 seconds to fetch the results, whereas the second procedure `zsp_select_Transactions2` took ONLY 1 SECOND!

I'm shocked to see such different results but I can only guess that this is due to the first procedure being executed every single second by many users?

When I was testing the procedure in my local PC I was getting almost identical execution time of 1 second like the `zsp_select_Transactions2` procedure...

What am I missing out here guys? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Short answer: probably. Long answer: Do you *really* need the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Did you honestly only try it once or did you try it a lot with same results?

Comment: @JacobH well no, not really... But is it really possible that I can't avoid this performance issue simply because it's executed by many users?? Maybe by caching it or something like that ? =(

Comment: @JoePhillips sometimes I get even worse results on first one =(

Comment: @JoePhillips could it be that I'm getting 30 seconds + results due to the fact it gets executed by 1000  + users at once?

Comment: Something may have changed between creating the two SPs? Such as the volume of data, statistics, indexes, etc?  Have you tried rerunning the CREATE statement for the first SP?

Comment: It *could* be. But we can't tell just from this information. Could be parameter sniffing. Could be locking. Could be a cached plan.

Comment: @MatBailie Oh that's correct I have added another index on the datetime column because it's contained in the WHERE statement... Could that be it ?

Comment: @JoePhillips Is ORDER BY heavy on the execution time ? Should I remove it ?

Comment: The original isn't using the new index. It's used so frequently the cached plan never expires, so a new plan with the new index is never created. Rerun the create statement and you'll invalidate the plan, a new one will then be created with knowledge of the new index.

Comment: @MatBailie got it , it executes within 1 second now =D ... But I still have terrible loading time on my web application, damn it..

Comment: Yes, order by is terrible performance, in most cases. Since you ignored the last comments I made trying to help you, I assume you will not heed this advice either, so good luck...

Comment: PARAMETER SNIFFING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "parameter sniffing" problem. [Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/):

> SQL Server compiles the stored procedures using (sniffing) the parameters send the first time the procedure is compiled and put it in plan cache. After that every time the procedure executed again, SQL Server retrieves the execution plan from the cache and uses it (unless there is a reason for recompilation).
>
> **The potential problem arises when the first time the stored procedure is executed, the set of parameters generate an acceptable plan for that set of parameters but very bad for other more common sets of parameters.**
>
> There are some workarounds to overcome this problem.

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE=VALUE))
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE UNKNOWN))
Use local variables
```

Using first alternative:

```
create procedure [dbo].[zsp_select_Transactions]
    (@SearchedUserId int,
     @StartDate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime)
as
     select 
         et.TransactionID, et.QuantityPurchased, 
         et.SalePrice, et.ItemID, et.Title
     from 
         Transactions et
     where 
         et.SearchedUserID = @SearchedUserId
         and et.TransactionDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
     order by 
         et.TransactionDate desc
     option (recompile);
```